# TypeError: printArea() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, class, oop

I created a class that finds the area of a rectangle. The problem I have is that the printArea() method gives me a type error whenever I try to check an instance of the class and I don't know what is wrong.

```
class Rectangle:
    length = 0;
    breadth = 0;
    def __init__(self, length, breadth):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth
    def setLength(self, length):
        self.length = length
    def getLength(self):
        return self.length
    def setBreadth(self, breadth):
        self.breadth = breadth
    def getBreadth(self):
        return self.breadth
    def calculateArea(self):
        Area = self.getLength() * self.getBreadth()
        return Area
    def printArea(self):
        Area = self.getLength() * self.getBreadth()
        print ("The area is %d" % (Rectangle.Area))
```

If I try `x = Rectangle(7,4)` and then try`x.printArea()`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#229>", line 1, in <module>
x.printArea()
TypeError: printArea() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: I can't reproduce. I'm getting an `AttributeError: type object 'Rectangle' has no attribute 'Area'`, not a `TypeError: printArea() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

Comment: Also, don't use getters and setters. Many other languages use them because they have private and protected variable concepts. Python has no such concepts, so using them more often than not verbose and unnecessary. Just use the instance variables directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR

If I run your code I get `AttributeError: type object 'Rectangle' has no attribute 'Area'`. The code works if you change it to

```
def printArea(self):
    area = self.getLength() * self.getBreadth()
    print("The area is %d" % (area))
```

#### Longer answer

When you write `Rectangle.Area`, this does not give you the area of this current rectangle (which would be given by `self.getArea()`), instead you get the member `Area` of the class `Rectangle` (which does not exist).

With that said, you could get what you want by making `area` a property and calling it like this:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, breadth):
        self._length = length
        self.breadth = breadth

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.breath

    def printArea(self):
        print ("The area is %d" % (self.area))
```

Note also that get... and set... are heavily frowned upon in python, and accessing the member is totally fine. If you truly need them, you should use properties with getters and setters

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, breadth):
        self.length = length
        self.breadth = breadth

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        self._length = value
```